# Unable to install extras & info.........Error codes: 0x80070002 and 0x80070003

Tags: windows-10-mobile, store, nokia-lumia-535, error

I am all updated but cannot install "Extras & info". It starts downloading and download till full 9.68MB then gives following error msg.

[image]

Is this a bug ? as I have been suffering from this problem since I have updated my phone on W10M. No problem for any other app. What I am doing wrong? My phone is  dual sim Lumia 535 (RM-1090) running W10M (14393.448) if relevant.
I have been trying since long and Now it gives following error msg.

[image]

What should I do now?

Comment: Have you tried soft resetting??

Comment: Tried......but that did'nt work. :(